# Crystal Reports Record Selection with IN Condition

Tags: crystal-reports

So I have kind of a fun problem. I have a record selection and part of it has an IN condition on my services table. Which works as expected. However, I want to also show Users who also received NO services. Here is what I have;

```
({table.SERVICE_CODE} in 
['ABC123','123ABC','DEF456'])
```

I am having a difficult time figuring this one out. But I imagine it working something like;

```
(({table.SERVICE_CODE} in 
['ABC123','123ABC','DEF456'])
OR count({table.SERVICE_CODE})=0)
```

What I am finding is that isNull or = "" etc. will not work because there is no row there for it to be null or blank against. Count wont work in a record selection because it cant evaluate that prior to having records to count.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you pulling from a single table, or are you joining in multiple tables?

Comment: @RobbieToyota Just the one.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question then. Specifically the part where you say you want to show certain data ("users"), but you can't because there's no rows [to be null or blank against]. What is the source of the user data that you want to display? It may help if you provide the structure of your table, and perhaps some sample data. This sounds like a relatively simple problem to solve, but it depends how your data is structured.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this may can help you OR can give you some idea

1) Create a formula to identify user receive service or not, for example the name for the formula is : NullService

```
If ISNULL ({table.ServiceCode}) then ''
```

2) Put together with your first formula.